# Class cast exception when creating elasticsearch SortOptions using builder withJson()

Tags: java, json, sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a [SortOptions](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.7.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/_types/SortOptions.html) object for an elastic search query using the [Create API objects from JSON data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/loading-json.html#loading-json) method. But I keep getting the following exception:

```
class co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$3 cannot be cast to class co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer (co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$3 and co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$3 cannot be cast to class co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer (co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$3 and co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at co.elastic.clients.util.WithJsonObjectBuilderBase.withJson(WithJsonObjectBuilderBase.java:53)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.WithJson.withJson(WithJson.java:57)
    at ElasticsearchFromJsonTest.lambda$parseSortOptions$0(ElasticsearchFromJsonTest.java:27)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.SortOptions.of(SortOptions.java:119)
    at ElasticsearchFromJsonTest.parseSortOptions(ElasticsearchFromJsonTest.java:27)
...
```

Code sample:

```
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.SortOptions;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class ElasticsearchFromJsonTest {

    @Test
    void parseSortOptions(){

        String test = """
                {
                  "sort" : [
                    { "term" : "asc"}
                  ]
                }
                """;

        SortOptions so = SortOptions.of(b->b.withJson(new StringReader(test)));

    }

}
```

I've also tried setting `test` to:

```
[{"term" : "asc"}]
```

And got the same results.

Java client library version: `co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.7.1`